# How To use Row Level Write or Update Lock In Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to lock some specific rows for update or delete or insert and rest rows of the tables should remain unlocked i.e. available for any transaction whether read or write . Is it possible in mysql if yes then please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to use InnoDB engine, as MyISAM does not support row-level locks.

Next, if you perform update, MySQL will implicitly lock the scanned rows. But if you need explicit lock of the rows, you can use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement.

Comment: To clarify, you have to use `SELECT FOR UDPATE` in a transaction. The rows will only be locked for the duration of the transaction (until you execute COMMIT).

Comment: Thanks Darhazer & Marcus Adams, I used select for update and I am using innodb table with innodb_file_per_table but still my purpose is not solved. It locks the complete table which is not my requirement . I want to lock only some row. Please help me on this.

Comment: @NiteshKumar make sure the query uses index to resolve it's where clause - otherwise the whole table is locked